# A generalization of the Biot-Savart law for a number $n$ of wires with $n\geq 3$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

This question is not a homework-exercises, but a request if exist a general formula of Biòt-Savart. We suppose that I have three or more wires traversed by incoming and outgoing currents and I would calculate the resultant of the magnetic field in a generic point of the space.

I have this example where I have a square and in the vertex there are the currents, where $r$ it is the half-diagonal of the square.

[image]

**EDIT**: Added new drawing after the comments of the user @G. Smith because the previous drawing it is not correct the direction and the verse of $\mathbf{B}_{24}$.

[image]

If I wanted to find the summation of the magnetic fields due from the 4 (four) wires, hoping that the drawn vectors of the magnetic fields are drawing  correctly (if they are not correct or there is a different drawing, I am very happy to know my mistakes), I should to apply to each pair of wires (for example for $\mathbf{B}_{13}$) the relation:

$$\boxed{B_{13}=\frac{\mu_0 (+I_1+I_3)}{2\pi r}}$$
and
$$\boxed{B_{24}=\frac{\mu_0 (+I_4-I_2)}{2\pi r}}$$ or $$\boxed{B_{24}=\frac{\mu_0 (-I_4+I_2)}{2\pi r}}$$

Why must I algebraically sum the values of the wire currents? Is there a general formula of Biòt-Savart for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107753/discussion-on-question-by-sebastiano-a-generalization-of-the-biot-savart-law-for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

---

The magnitude of the magnetic field a distance $\:r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert \mathbf r \Vert\:$ from a long  straight wire carrying a steady current I, see Figure, is given by
\begin{equation} 
\mathrm B\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf B \Vert\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mu_0}{2\pi}\dfrac{\:\:\rm I\:\:}{r}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
while its direction is found by the right-hand rule.

Using the vectors $\:\mathbf I, \mathbf r\:$ and $\:\mathbf B\:$ in place of the scalar quantities $\:\mathrm I, r\:$ and $\:\mathrm B\:$ all these informations are contained in the following simple vector equation
\begin{equation} 
\boxed{\:\:\mathbf B \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mu_0}{2\pi}\dfrac{\:\:\mathbf I \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf r\:\:}{\Vert \mathbf r\Vert^2}\:\:}
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}
This is the Biot-Savart Law for a long  straight wire carrying a steady current I.

Note : the OP has confused above  Law with its use to find the (Lorentz) force per unit length between two parallel wires carrying parallel or anti-parallel steady currents.