# Magnetic field intensity and magnitude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How can i find the magnetic field intensity and magnitude in P ? Also around the first wire ?

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the PSE community. I remember that you can sum the magnetic fields and that you have a square of measure $a$.

Comment: I think that your question it similar to this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550087/a-generalization-of-the-biot-savart-law-for-a-number-n-of-wires-with-n-geq-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnetic field at point P is 0 because of mutual cancellation of fields by opposite wires. This can be seen easily if you use the screw rule for straight wires.

$$|\vec B_{straight\ wire}|=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$$

where r is perpendicular distance from wire