# Why do these 2 formulas about magnetic field conflict with each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, charge

$\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$

Magnetic Field of a current is:
$$B = \mu_0 I / (2 \pi r)\tl{01}$$
Magnetic Field of a Moving Charge is:
$$B = \mu_0 qv\sin\theta / (4\pi r^2)\tl{02}$$

So I have
$$\mu_0 I / (2\pi r) =  \mu_0 qv\sin\theta / (4\pi r^2)\implies I = qv\sin\theta / (2r)\tl{03}$$
Since $I = q/t$,
$$q/t = qv\sin\theta / (2r)\implies vt\sin\theta = 2r\tl{04}$$
Since $l = vt$,
$$l\sin\theta = 2r\implies\frac{l}{r}\sin\theta = 2\tl{05}$$
Since $l / r =\cos\theta$,
$$\cos\theta\sin\theta = 2\tl{06}$$

This equation has no solution. It doesn't make sense. Can someone please point out where I'm wrong at?

What I write is just what I think in my head, if you don't understand something, please ask me because you may not find it on any website.

Comment: Why do you think the formula for "a current" is applicable here? Ask yourself: What does the magnetic field of "a current" mean? A circular current? A current through an infinitely long wire? Something else?

Comment: current is an amount of charge passing a point in a wire per second. So I think they are related

Comment: The radius $r$ has different geometrical meanings in both formulas for $B$.
Therefore it is wrong to equate these two $r$.

Comment: I've edited your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). It makes Greek letters easier.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge). **(2)** [A generalization of the Biot-Savart law for a number  n  of wires with  n≥3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550087/a-generalization-of-the-biot-savart-law-for-a-number-n-of-wires-with-n-geq-3).

Answer (score 6):

Your first formula is for an (infinite ) straight line of moving charges.  The second is for only one of the charges in that line.

Comment: More specifically the first equation will fail for a single point charge because it assumes some contributions from left & right of observation point will cancel each other out.

Comment: With a cross product, extra contributions from segments of current do not cancel.